# codeigniter 4 not showing mysql full query when error occured

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

How to show full query string when occur errors. My query as follows

```
    $builder = $this->table("$this->table");
    $builder->select("usr_lock");
    $builder->where("usr_lock >= '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'");
    $builder->where($this->primarykey, $user_id);
    $r = $builder->get()->rowArray();
    echo "<br>Error: " . $builder->error();
    echo "<br>Last Query: " . $builder->getLastQuery();
    return $r['usr_lock'];
```

When execute this, it is showing errors as `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '1'' at line 4` . To know about the error I need to get full query. So I used `$builder->getLastQuery()`. But it is not executes. The page look like as
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `$builder->getCompiledSelect()` before executing the `$builder->get()`

```
    $builder = $this->table("$this->table");
    $this->db_debug = FALSE;
    $builder->select("usr_lock");
    $builder->where("usr_lock >= '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'");
    $builder->where($this->primarykey, $user_id);
    echo "<br>Last Query: " . $builder->getCompiledSelect(false);
    exit();
```